# How to set up cordova app as a screen saver

Tags: android, cordova, android-tv

I used this plugin https://github.com/frontyard/cordova-plugin-android-tv to make an app runnable on TV, but I can't see it when I try to change the screensaver. All I can see is default apps. My app at the moment is a template Cordova app with one plugin that I mentioned above.

[image]

Comment: How did you install it on your TV?

Comment: @Eric dragged and dropped the apk file. I used this instructions https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator#runningemulator

Comment: The instructions you referred to are about running the emulator?

Comment: @Eric sorry, it should redirect to a "Launch the Android Emulator without first running an app" section. I install the app on emulator via drag and drop.

Comment: @Eric sorry, can you help me?